# Using Named and optional arguments to distinguish between constructors

Tags: c#, constructor, optional-parameters, named-parameters

Imagine a class which can, in principle, be created by specifying the value of one of two properties, both of which happen to have the same type. The following code accomplishes this by using a combination of [named and optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) to discriminate between the two constructors:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {           
        //Note: these 2 ctors are distinguished only by the argument naming convention:
        thing thingWithMass = new thing(mass: 10);
        thing thingWithVolume = new thing(vol: 25);
    }

    class thing
    {
        int Density = 3;
        int Mass;
        int Vol;
        public thing(int mass)
        {
            Mass = mass;
            Vol = Mass/Density;
        }

        // Note the use of the optional variable to distinguish this ctor:
        public thing(int vol, bool isVol=true)
        {
            Vol = vol;
            Mass = Vol * Density;
        }
    }
}
```

So (somewhat surprisingly) this code compiles and works perfectly, but is it *bad form*? It seems a bit like trickery, and I'm wondering if there is a lurking danger that isn't readily apparent to me? Does it smell?

NOTE: In this particular case, I realize that I could accomplish essentially the same thing with a single constructor that looks like this:

```
public thing(int mass=0, int vol=0) //plus a couple of if() statements in the body
```

but in my real situation there are quite a few other parameters involved, and combining them all into one constructor gets a bit unwieldy and hard to read.

Comment: I'd say it smells a bit. Anyone using this class would have to know how to work with this trickery or they could wind up with unexpected results.

Comment: I think it would be best to show your real code because quite frankly right now I feel like asking why you even make a class (a reference type btw) to wrap an integer value.

Comment: @Crono: my class is far more complex than this; for this example I just stripped out everything that wasn't necessary to demonstrate the constructor logic.

Comment: @kmote can't you split your class into several ones? IMHO it doesn't make sense for a class to sometimes be about volume only and sometimes mass only. And it most definitely isn't friendly at all to make its whole nature depend on which of its constructor has been used.

Comment: @Crono: I've updated the code snippet to make the design logic a bit clearer, but I'm afraid you're missing the gist of my question.

Comment: @kmote The question is about code smells. And yes, it does smell. But (again, IMHO) the biggest smell here is using the same class to represent two kinds of values. I think before even questioning how you are using constructors, you might want to question how your class should be defined. If the two values shares some behaviors then you should put these behaviors in a base class and create two derived classes. Your code would be a lot safer, cleaner and most likely easier to read as well.

Answer (score 3):

If your class has many constructors with very different logic and conflicting types of arguments, consider using static factory methods:

```
public static Thing CreateFromMass(int mass)
{
    return new Thing(mass, 0);
}

public static Thing CreateFromVol(int vol)
{
    return new Thing(0, vol);
}
```

You can make your constructor non-public if you use factory methods like this.

Distinguishing constructors based on parameter names, while possible, is not recommended, because it is very uncommon in C#. Note that you are also forced to use tricks with optional parameters to achive this — a clear indicator that you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

IMO it's a bit of a smell. What if a consumer calls `thing(10, false)`. That has the unintended consequence of creating `thing` with the wrong value.

I can think of two possible solutions

1) Use a factory as described by Athari.

2) Create types for Mass and Volume. For example,

```
class Mass 
{
    private readonly int _mass;
    public Mass(int mass) { _mass = mass; }
    public int Value { get { return _mass; } } 
}

class Volume
{
    private readonly int _volume;
    public Mass(int volume) { _volume = volume; }
    public int Value { get { return _volume; } } 
}
```

You can then change your signatures to

```
thing(Volume volume)
thing(Mass mass)
```

In response to your comment about simple arithmetic operations not working with the second approach, you can define implicit conversions to and from `int` for `Mass` and `Volume`.

```
abstract class Number
{
    public static implicit operator int(Number number)
    {
        return number.Value;
    }

    public abstract  int Value { get; set; }
}

internal class Mass : Number
{
    public override int Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator Mass(int val) { return new Mass(){ Value = val }; }
}

internal class Volume : Number
{
    public static implicit operator Volume(int val) { return new Volume(){ Value = val }; }
    public override int Value { get; set; }
}

var mass = new Mass { Value = 10 };
var volume = new Volume { Value = 20 };
int product = mass * volume; // should work
mass = 10 * 20; // should also work
```

Comment: np, glad I could help!

Comment: Another great suggestion (and a great point about the unintended consequence). Thank you!

Comment: While I still think your suggestion is useful, it has some ramifications that I'm uncomfortable with. For example, simple equations like `mass = volume * density` must be transformed into `mass = new Mass(volume.value * density.value), which will make more complex equations much harder to read. But thanks for helping me think outside the box!

Comment: you can achieve that using implicit an conversion

Comment: Thanks for your continuing help, but your abstract class doesn't build in its current form. (static operator can't access non static property).

Comment: which line specifically? I copy pasted the example from vs but it's possible I missed something